# how to get the second simoperatorname in android below lollipop

Tags: android

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getSimOperatorName();
```

by using the telephonymanger getting the simone operatorname,but i want secondsim operatorname .

Comment: Only way is to write code for every phone model separately since every manufacturer made their own firmware modification, and their own API for dual sim before it was introduced by google. So basically it doesn't worth to do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is not support in the Android SDK for multiple SIM cards. Only we can get the name of the Current Network Operator or SIM operator and in case you dont have sim the result will be "".
This will work but only for the main operator
From API 22, now you can check for multiple SIM cards. Check out Android Docs :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29

**For API >=22:**

```
final SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
    final List<SubscriptionInfo> activeSubscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
    for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : activeSubscriptionInfoList) {
        final CharSequence carrierName = subscriptionInfo.getCarrierName();
        final CharSequence displayName = subscriptionInfo.getDisplayName();
        final int mcc = subscriptionInfo.getMcc();
        final int mnc = subscriptionInfo.getMnc();
        final String subscriptionInfoNumber = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();
    }
```

**For API >=23**

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (manager.getPhoneCount() == 2) {
    // Dual sim
}
```